# How to make height of two div same dynamically when orientation changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fieldset" id="myform1">List 1 
        <a class="ui-shadow ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-gear" value="SUBMIT" id="sub2"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="hidenset" id="myformMenu1" style="display:none;">Menu 1</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to give the `fieldset` and `hiddenset` divs the same height in mobile devices when the orientation changes.

**Script**

```
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        $('div.parent').each(function(){
              var h = $(this).find('fieldset').height();
              $(this).find('hidenset').attr('height',h+'px');

        });
```

but this script is not working properly

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Use the [`window.onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize) event, which should fire whenever the viewport size changes.

Comment: More on Blazemonger's comment: http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change

Comment: Also, fieldset can be it's own tag - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp

Comment: @Blazemonger or use [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0).

Comment: @dwhite.me I updated my code please have a look

Comment: You misspelled `hiddenset` in your script sample.

Comment: @Blazemonger fixed it bro still no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class selectors in jQuery need to be prefixed with a `.` -- also, you misspelled `hiddenset`.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    $('div.parent').each(function(){
          var h = $(this).find('.fieldset').height();
          $(this).find('.hiddenset').height(h);
    });
});
```